# Why return type of producer methods in projected generic types with upper bound is Any? instead of upper bound type?

Tags: generics, kotlin

Consider this setup:

```
open class Base
open class Derived: Base()

interface Foo<T: Base> {
    fun produce(): T
    fun consume(aT: T)
}
```

Following functions are valid:

```
fun apply1(f: Foo<*>) {
    val p: Base = f.produce();
}

fun apply2(f: Foo<Derived>) {
    val p: Base = f.produce();
}
```

but this one is not:

```
fun apply3(f: Foo<in Derived>) {
    val p: Base = f.produce();
}
```

> Type mismatch
>   Required: Base
>   Found: Any?

Generic type parameter `T` has an upper bound. So it could be safely considered as a sub type of `Base` as it is done in `apply1` and `apply2`. The question is why it is not valid to do the same when it is projected with `in`?

Comment: Good question. It looks like explicitly `in`-projecting the type makes the `out` type `Any?` instead of `Base` like it does with star projection. I don't see why it needs to do that. Star projection can safely assume the `out` type is at least the upper bound `Base`. That's true when we know nothing of the type, and should be no less true when we know the `in` type.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Exactly! No matter what kind of projection is used, `T: Base` is a valid assumption.

Comment: @Ehsan Agree that `T: Base` is a valid assumption regardless of use-site projection. In my answer below I show one could still read `T: Base` in type-safe way. But it doesn't explain (for myself as well) why with `Foo<in Derived>` it can't automaticaly be assumed `Foo<out Base>`

Answer (score 0):

These keywords are *designed* for restriction, you specify it when you want to ensure your user won't both read and write values from the object.
The flaws it tries to avoid are explained in Kotlin [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance) (Variance + Type projection).

The *in* keyword only allows for *consumption* by annotated target, and *out* one is made for *production* of values. Your apply3 function should use the *out* keyword to specify that the aim is to *only produce* values from foo parameter.

In opposite, *in* places a restriction to specify that you'll give *Foo* objects to *consume, and only that*.

Comment: While I agree with your point that these keywords are designed for restriction, I think that they are not meant to prevent the client code from calling consumer or producer functions (as you can still call producer functions in an `in`-projected instace). They just help the compiler to ensure type safety at compile time. In `apply3` function, it is totally safe to cast return value of `produce` function to `Base` so there's nothing _unsafe_ here to be taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

If you can read (using `out` projection) and write (using `in` projection) as separate statements, you can do the following. Note that there's no unsafe typecasting.

```kotlin
fun apply4(f: Foo<in Derived>) {
    f.consume(Derived())
    val fOutProjected = f as Foo<out Base>
    val p: Base = fOutProjected.produce();
}
```

With star (`*`) projection, it's possible to produce results of upper bound `Base` same as in `out` projection, but not to consume anything, as it's possible with `in` projection.
The following is impossible:

```kotlin
fun apply5(f: Foo<*>) {
    f.consume(Derived()) // <- won't compile
    val p: Base = f.produce();
}
```